# Buddhism on suicide

Tags: life, suicide, buddhist

I want to know how *suicide* is viewed in Buddhism. I know that it is not viewed positively, but I want to know why. Is it because it brings grief to others? Is that the only reason? Or there is something else..? 
I think that if you die happily in a calm state because you wish to, there is no negative energy within you.. so I don't understand why suicide is such a bad thing. *(the reasons I think are the grief that will bring to the family and that one's negative energy will linger)*

Buddhism also varies among countries and cultures (I'm from the East Asia), but I believe it all began with the core teachings of Buddha and I just want to learn his teachings.

Thank you.

Comment: There related topics with relevant answers, which are also [tagged with the 'suicide' tag](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suicide).

Answer (score 5):

Generally, a calm & happy person is not inclined to commit suicide. Generally, a person thinks about committing suicide because they are unhappy & suffering from *emotional* pain.

In the Pali suttas, only enlightened beings are reported to have ended life. This occurred in at least two situations:

1. Terminal illness with totally disabling pain (e.g. [MN 144](http://www.yellowrobe.com/component/content/article/120-majjhima-nikaya/286-channovda-sutta-advice-to-channa.html)), which was unblameworthy.
2. Revulsion towards the meaningless of phenomena (e.g. [SN 54.9](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn54/sn54.009.than.html)), which was both unpraiseworthy & unnecessary.

If a person commits suicide because of *emotional suffering*, in Buddhism, this is considered to be unpraiseworthy for at least three reasons:

1. craving exists for a certain state of being;
2. faith has not been placed in the Buddha, Dhamma, Sangha & Noble Eightfold Path to overcome the emotional pain & suffering, which can be overcome with right practise; and
3. it can result in suffering arising in other people, such as mother, father, family & friends.

Answer (score 3):

Possible list of reasons for not condoning suicide:

- You are intentionally taking a life which is breaking Sila and Vinaya
- It bring social problems like misery to loved ones and oftens dependents
- The act is done with negative mental state hence does not lead to beneficial rebirth in the next life.
- Based on the view of extinction or nihilism which is unskillful

More on this see:

- Introduction to [Chann’ovāda Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/11.12-Channovada-S-m144-piya.pdf) by Piya Tan
- [Death: An early Buddhist perspective](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/48.2-Death-An-early-Buddhist-perspective.-piya.pdf) by Piya Tan

Comment: Hi Suminda. My understanding is, taking your own life is not breaking the first precept. I agree with you but this Is how I made to understand in other forums. I can't support my claim with sutta. This is just hearsay information.

Comment: **Pārājika 3** forbids this for monks. It may be disputed for Sila. But Pārājika are the most offensive breaks of Vinaya hence I think this breaks Sila also.

Answer (score 1):

Suicide is the result of hatred towards yourself, perhaps others or a thing (sickness). Hatred is an unwholesome mental state which will result in a birth in a lower realm.

This is a disputed subject in Buddhism. There is an extended discussion at this link: https://dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=27879&hilit=

Comment: I don't think it's necessarily hatred towards self. It could be hatred of the life conditions one finds oneself in.